# Writing dictionnary of dataframe into an excel file produce error

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the key are string and the values are dataframe (pandas data series). I want to write the whole dictionary to an excel file.

I want each key to be the sheetname of file and each value to be reported in sheet. But the following code just add the last key and values and omitting the others.

```
for key, val in dico2.items():
        #print(key)
        #print(val)
        print(type(val))
        val.to_excel(outdir_report + "/report_for_{}.xlsx".format(n), sheet_name=key, encoding ="utf-8")
```

dico

```
dico2 = {'Model_SVC_ovr':                   C    F         M  accuracy  macro avg  weighted avg
precision  0.625000  0.0  0.500000       0.5   0.375000      0.402778
recall     0.833333  0.0  0.571429       0.5   0.468254      0.500000
f1-score   0.714286  0.0  0.533333       0.5   0.415873      0.445503
support    6.000000  5.0  7.000000       0.5  18.000000     18.000000, 'Model_SVC_ov':                   C    F         M  accuracy  macro avg  weighted avg
precision  0.625000  0.0  0.500000       0.5   0.375000      0.402778
recall     0.833333  0.0  0.571429       0.5   0.468254      0.500000
f1-score   0.714286  0.0  0.533333       0.5   0.415873      0.445503
support    6.000000  5.0  7.000000       0.5  18.000000     18.000000}
```

What I get :

[image]

As you see, sheetname for model_ovr is not present. Maybe you can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new Excel file instead of writing to existing one. That is why only the last one shows up. You could create a writer and use that to write all sheets:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(outdir_report + "/report_for_{}.xlsx".format(n)) as writer:  
    for key, val in dico2.items():
        val.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key, encoding ="utf-8")
```

Comment: thank you , do you think it is possible to write  in the same sheet instead on another sheet, should I use set the key the same ?

Comment: @kely789456123 consider this approach: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46437/how-to-write-multiple-data-frames-in-an-excel-sheet/46451